# I have a text file that has 2 columns I need to merge all lines in column 2 before the next column 1 attribute id

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, notepad

Have only ever dealt with very simple text to csv data formatting. I am working with a text file with 14900 lines for a mapping project. I have tried delimiting using tab etc but cannot get a single text string for a single attribute ID in the first column. Each attribute ID is supposed to have a single text string attribute but has multiple separated lines per attribute ID (as per screenshot). I would love some direction on creating a single text string per attribute id. The txt document is called explanatory notes and is located on the ASRIS CSIRO website here if thats any help.
https://www.asris.csiro.au/downloads/Atlas/soilAtlas2M.zip.
or look at the screenshot of what I mean. [image: screenshot]

thanks so much

target data needs to look like this the description is potentially a 200 long character text string with no carriage return or line feed It's not pretty but to import it to my map I cant have multiple line feeds for one description

| Att ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

[screenshot of target data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiSJO.jpg)

Comment: Please show an example of what is your target. Do you need to concatenate table cells?

Comment: Thanks, @harrymc I think it is concatenated table cells but I cannot get it to perform using a column separated by a new attribute id in column A. I edited my post to show an example of what my target looks like.

Comment: It it's a text file, maybe a GREP search in a good text editor would allow you to remove carriage returns not followed by an Atttribute ID. There may be a few false positives, so manual checking will still be needed, but it would go a long way towards fixing the file.

Comment: Thankyou @cybernetic.nomad I'll look into that see how I go. thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Use the code in the first lines as an example of how to read a text file into Power Query

  - In my case, I stored the extracted file on my desktop
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Text/CSV
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Path in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the path in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Use non-existent character for delimiter to keep from splitting anything
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\explanatoryNotes.txt"),
        [Delimiter=Character.FromNumber(1), Columns=1, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Blank Rows",{{"Column1", "Explanatory Notes"}}),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Renamed Columns",1),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Top Rows", "Custom", each 
    
        //replace first space with a SOH
        let 
            noteList = Text.ToList([Explanatory Notes]),
            firstSpace = List.PositionOf(noteList," ",Occurrence.First),
            replWithPlaceHolder = List.ReplaceRange(noteList,firstSpace,1,{Character.FromNumber(1)}),
            theString = Text.Combine(replWithPlaceHolder)
        in 
            theString),

//Remove original column, then split on that first SOH
//should leave a space in first column which can be replaced with null
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Explanatory Notes"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({Character.FromNumber(1)}, 
        QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Attribute ID","Explanatory Note"}),

//Trim any leading (and trailing) spaces
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{
            {"Attribute ID", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Explanatory Note", Text.Trim, type text}}),

//Replace empty cells in Attribute Column with Nulls to enable fill down
    addNulls = Table.TransformColumns(#"Trimmed Text",{{"Attribute ID", each if Text.Length(_)=0 then null else _, type text}}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(addNulls,{"Attribute ID", "Explanatory Note"}),

//Group by ID (with groupkind.local in case there are separate identical groups)
//  and concatenate the Note lines
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Attribute ID"}, {
        {"Explanatory Notes", each Text.Combine([Explanatory Note]," "), type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

***Output of some rows***
[image]

Comment: Wow, that looks neat as. Thank you very much for your help @Ron Rosenfeld that is exactly what I need !!!

Comment: @Sarah Glad to help. Since my answer seems to be what you require, kindly mark it as Accepted.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: This worked like a treat. It took me a little while to work it out as I don't have much experience but I got there. Thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

just for the sake of providing alternative solution here's how this text can be extracted using Linux shell with `cat` `tr` `awk` and `sed` :

prepare index file:

```
cat explanatoryNotes.txt|grep -v ^' '|awk '{print $1}' > indexes
```

remove all new lines from the text file:

```
cat explanatoryNotes.txt|tr -d '\n' > explanatoryNotes.txt-no_newlines
```

search & replace all indexes with index+newline:

```
for i in `cat indexes`;do sed -i 's/'"\\${i} "'/'"\\${nl}${i} "'/g' explanatoryNotes.txt-no_newlines;done
```

this text manipulation expects index group of characters to occur only at the beginning of the line (and not within the text) to work properly.

Comment: Thanks very much. I was able to utilize the other suggested process but will have a look at this when I get time. thanks again